# Do you add PP bonus to vehicle dodge bonus as per HtH combat?

Tags: rifts, palladium-system

My GM is having issues with adding high PP bonus to jet fighter dodge rolls. He isn't seeing bonus from high PP (e.g. 27 PP, +6 TO to combat HtH & vehicle dodge). I am proficient in jet-fighter combat elite & the vehicle. Please provide references with answers!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. When referencing Palladium material, as the Palladium canon is vast and entropic, it's good to be as specific as possible. For example, I tend to include the name of the text and year the text was published, and this question would've benefited from including where the skills can be found. Also, Palladium's tendency toward stealth errata means that books published even a year apart can be very different, and even *more* different if they're actually labeled as *revised* or whatever. Have fun, and thank you for participating.

Answer (score 2):

*Rifts Dimension Book 2: Phase World* (1994) on Fighters and Small Vessel Combat on page 151 describes bonuses for the skill Fighter Combat "Elite" Combat Training. These bonuses include…

- 2 extra attacks/actions with the fighter's weapon and +1 additional attack/action at levels 5 and 10.
- +2 to strike with the fighter's weapons that's cumulative with the skill Weapon Systems.
- +5 to dodge while flying the fighter.
- +3 to dog-fighting rolls (with the text describing dog-fighting).
- Using the pilot's hand-to-hand-combat-skill-modified chance of a critical strike with the fighter's weapons.

While the text doesn't mention adding the pilot's bonuses from Physical Prowess (P.P.) to the vehicle's dodge rolls, the same page *does* say that during a dog-fight

> the player for each pilot rolls a 20 sided die, adding their dog-fighting bonus (including P.P. bonuses), [*sic*] and any ship movement bonuses. The faster or more maneuverable of the two vessels gets a +2 to the roll. The winner gets to be the the *dog tail*. The loser is the *dog*.

(Emphasis as per the original.) Maybe this is this belief's origin? Anyway, I know that somewhere in the *Rifts* canon there *are* vehicles that are more responsive than others (skycycles perhaps?) and *those* may specifically allow adding the pilot's P. P. bonuses to his vehicle's dodge attempts, but Fighter Combat "Elite" Combat Training in *Phase World* doesn't mention this.

Just to confirm there wasn't *another* Jet Fighter Combat: Elite skill (because, c'mon… *Rifts*… whatdyagonnado?), I looked at four claiming-to-be complete lists of *Rifts* skills: two mentioned this *Phase World* skill, and the other two didn't mention this or any other one. Maybe the rules you're using say that this skill actually does what you want it do, but the skill itself is of no help in backing you up.

Comment: @lly I prefer to have the structure go from biggest to smallest when discussing a text, and that means book to section to subsection with a final reference for page. Also, I try to transcribe quotations from texts accurately, and the edit made me go back to the original text and confirm that the error that was corrected by the edit existed in the original. I didn't *sic* it originally because I figured no one but me would really care—so, in sum, *thank you* for caring enough to make my text better, and I apologize for my quirks! `:-)`

Comment: It's ok. Nothing against you, your typesetting, or your citation idiom. Pending anything I can answer better than you guys have already done, I'm just going around editing answers to questions I'm curious about anyway to bump my rep up high enough to at least downvote bad answers.